# __DATE__ and __TIME__ compilation

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

I am using CMake for my projet and one of the file "tools.cpp" contains

```
__DATE__ and __TIME__
```

to get the compilation time. However, this file is not compiled every time which means that if I change only main.cpp, I will not obtain the last compilation time.

How can I obtain the last compilation time whatever the file I changed? Thanks.

Comment: Add a make rule to the make file such that the touch utility is called on the tools.cpp file.

Comment: Have you tried adding a dependency between `tools.o` and all other object files in the project?

Comment: It would be a good idea, but I don't really know how to to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the *build* time and date, you have two options:  1) Rebuild all; 2) Create a tool that changes the date and time.

In our system, we have a file with the function:

```
std::string
Get_Build_Date()
{
  return "06/28/2023";
}
```

We wrote a script that replaces the date string in the function with the build date.

This allows a minimum building of only the date file.

**Edit 1: Alternative: touching files**
You may be able to modify the makefile so that the date file is "touched".  The *nix operating systems have a command `touch` which will set the modification date of a file to the present time and date.